# Write html tags form one file to another

Tags: javascript, php, html

Need to write html elements into another file

Need the html elements in file1.php (below)

```
<code><div class="ui-draggable"><div class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" contenteditable="true">
                    <h2 contenteditable="true">Heading 2</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" contenteditable="true">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit,
                        <br>sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                        <br>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><div class="row-tool"><div class="row-handle"><i class="cb-icon-move"></i></div>
    <div class="row-html"><i class="cb-icon-code"></i></div><div class="row-copy">
    <i class="cb-icon-plus"></i></div><div class="row-remove"><i class="cb-icon-cancel"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

to be write into a div called  id="contentarea" in content.php.

It only seems to display on screen, but in view source in browser the "contentarea" div is empty.

have been trying for 2 days now and can't work it out.

Comment: you want it display on screen but dont exist in page source?

Answer (score 2):

If you `include` a php file, in a specific location, like inside this `div` of yours, it will bring in that file.

```
<div id="contentarea">
    <?php include "file1.php"; ?>
</div>
```

This will work fine so long as file1.php only has the elements you need, because everything is included. HTML tag, head tags, body, etc.

The reason your view source isn't showing these elements is because the source code is transfered via HTTP header. So anything dynamic (say, an AJAX import of HTML) will not be shown. Check the inspect element section of the console for that.

Comment: never heard of php import. Seen it in css and can't find references to it in php online manual. please can you explain in more detail

Comment: Apologies, I've spent too much time in python/nodejs/java recently. I meant to say `include` not `import`

Comment: never heard of php import. Seen it in css and can't find references to it. But I owe you a beer as you kick my brain into gear. I had my test page as html not php and a simple php include worked. 2 days wasted for a small stupid mistake